# How to detect right mouse click + paste using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to detect a right click followed by paste with JavaScript on IE and Firefox ?

Update:

I decided to use Jquery to do it:

```
$('#controlId').bind('paste', null, function() {
    // code
});
```

It's not exactly what I was looking (because it gets fired on 'ctrl + v' as well as in 'right click + paste' but I can work around it.

Tested it on Chrome, Firefox 3, IE 7 and IE 6 and it's working

Comment: I'm afraid.  What are you trying to do ?  I think depending on the right click and paste has serious web usability issues.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean "detect a right click followed by paste" or "detect a right click, then do a paste"?

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed the title and added more text to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Guido García: I'm using the ajax control toolkit autocomplete extender, the problem is that it doesn't autocomplete when you paste text using the mouse on IE (works on Firefox and using ctrl+v works on both) so I'm trying to catch the event to fire the autocomplete. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With IE you have onpaste

With Mozilla you can look into
oninput
and

```
elementReference.addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified", function(e){ foo(e);}, false);
```

There is no easy as pie solution.

Eric

Comment: Can you please provide a full example for both IE and Firefox? Thank you. Also, what about Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 83):

I like this solution:

```
$('#txt_field').bind('input propertychange', function() {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Awesome! How did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Just so people know, this fires on cut as well as paste.

Comment: This is  awesome solution

Comment: I was curious as to which bind did what, but in the end I only needed "input" to catch keyboard entry, keyboard paste and mouse paste events.

Answer (score 23):

```
$('#controlId').bind('paste', null, function(e) {
    if(!e.keyCode){
       /*
          since no key was down at the time of the event we can assume it was
          from the toolbar or right click menu, and not a ctrl+v
       */
    }
});
```

Comment: Quirksmode says this is a pretty solid solution: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Answer (score 5):

Use `setTimeout()`, set small timeout till .val() func can get populated.

```
$(document).on('paste blur keyup', '#controlId', function(event) {
    var element = $(event.target);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var text = $(element).val();
        // do something with text
    }, 100);
});
```

Source: [Catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/catch-paste-input)

Answer (score 1):

if you're using vue you can emit and pass pasted value like so:

```
 <v-text-field 
   @input="$emit('rightclickpaste',$event)"  
 >             
 </v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IE8. Chrome was allowing me to recognize a right click paste, but IE8 was not.

I was able to fix the issue with JQUERY using the mouse leave function as described by Aaron, but here is the code:

```
for IE8:
    $( "#field" ).mouseleave(function() {
                doStuff());
            });

for Chrome:
    $('#field').bind('input',function() {
                doStuff();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following which only fires on mouseup:

```
onmouseup="jQuery(this).on('paste',function(event){setTimeout(function(){alert('Paste detected!');},100);});"
```

Answer (score -1):

A cheap hack (that works) that you can try is:

- jQuery's mouseleave function.

I've noticed with IE8 that if you right-click in a text box and then select 'paste', it delays the "mouseleave" event until the paste has finished. So it consistently fires right after the paste! :) Works for me and got me out of trouble perfectly actually.

This is only for an intranet app, I haven't tested in Firefox etc.

Cheers