# Catch paste input

Tags: jquery, paste, sanitize

I'm looking for a way to sanitize input that I paste into the browser, is this possible to do with jQuery?

I've managed to come up with this so far:

```
$(this).live(pasteEventName, function(e) {
 // this is where i would like to sanitize my input
 return false;
}
```

Unfortunately my development has come to a screeching hold because of this "minor" issue.
I would really make me a happy camper if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Please mark http://stackoverflow.com/a/1503425/749232 as the answer for the use of other people experiencing the same issue. That solved it for me.

Comment: .live() is deprecated as of jquery 1.9, they recommend .on() instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19269040/530153

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I sort of fixed it by using the following code:

```
$("#editor").live('input paste',function(e){
    if(e.target.id == 'editor') {
        $('<textarea></textarea>').attr('id', 'paste').appendTo('#editMode');
        $("#paste").focus();
        setTimeout($(this).paste, 250);
    }
});
```

Now I just need to store the caret location and append to that position then I'm all set... I think :)

Comment: How did you store the caret location?

Comment: @Petah You could check which element has focus with `.find(':focus')`, and knowing that element determine caret location for it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea).

Comment: Remember that "live" is deprecated in favor of "on"

Comment: `input` makes the difference :) I normally have these in my textbox events `keyup keydown paste input` but obviously depends what your motives are

Answer (score 349):

OK, just bumped into the same issue.. I went around the long way

```
$('input').on('paste', function () {
  var element = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var text = $(element).val();
    // do something with text
  }, 100);
});
```

Just a small timeout till .val() func can get populated.

E.

Comment: What if there is text in the textarea already and you paste, and you just wanted the pasted text?

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.  A timeout of 0 works just as well.  The function just needs deferred to the next loop.

Comment: @barfoon Just make sure to clean the textarea at the end of your timeout, *after* you've grabbed the value. This way it's restored to the clean state after each paste.

Comment: sry but i don't get it. What do i want with the alert? How do i properly return it so this gets pasted? And why does this clean the code? Why the timeout?

Comment: Just been in a similar situation. The timeout is there because the paste event isn't immediate, but takes a few milliseconds for the clipboard content to be pasted in.

Comment: @user563811: Just do note that the official minimum timeout is 4ms in HTML5.

Comment: Like sharif says, 0ms still puts the event at the bottom of the stack.

Comment: yeah, it works on Chrome, Safari and Firefox! How about msie 6 7 8 9 10? $("input:text").bind("paste copy cut", function(event) { console.log(event.type) });

Comment: I believe `.on()` is preferable to `.bind()` now.

Comment: @pimvdb Most browsers interpret 0 to mean, "let any pending updates run first".  There's the standard, and then there's what everyone does.  BobRodes has a more technical explanation.

Comment: This will accept pasting by keyboard shortcut on an input field, even if it's readonly. You could test for `$(this).is('[readonly]')` within the block.

Comment: I would like to have a <button> next to a textarea and have whatever is in the clipboard pasted into the textarea. Could somebody throw together a jsfiddle showing how this would be done?

Comment: I know this is old - but you should also do this for "blur", since someone can paste - and before RELEASING the keys, click outside the box with the mouse - and this event won't fire.  Adding blur solves this problem.

Answer (score 80):

You can actually grab the value straight from the [event](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis). Its a bit obtuse how to get to it though.

Return false if you don't want it to go through.

```
$(this).on('paste', function(e) {

  var pasteData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text')

});
```

Comment: This is the way to go

Comment: ie 11: window.clipboardData.getData('text')

Comment: However, note that the need of the "originalEvent" property is only needed if you are handling the event with jQuery. You can do just `e.clipboardData.getData('text')` in plain JavaScript.

Comment: Best answer here!  But -- I found it odd that the short-hand version of binding's doesn't work with this, i.e., error if I try this: $(this).paste(function(e) {...});, even though that works for short-handing .on('click'), etc..

Comment: niggle: the code is missing a closing paren.  Apparently the change is too smal to allow me to fix it as an edit.

Answer (score 46):

For cross platform compatibility, it should handle oninput and onpropertychange events:

```
$ (something).bind ("input propertychange", function (e) {
    // check for paste as in example above and
    // do something
})
```

Comment: Beautiful solution that works as both paste and keyup event catching.
**Note:** This causes the event function to fire twice for some reason if you highlight the input contents _and then_ type something in _at least IE8_ (not important in many cases, but possibly very important in others).

Comment: Nice ! I didn't know about this one, and it fits perfectly my needs !

Answer (score 10):

Hmm... I *think* you can use `e.clipboardData` to catch the data being pasted. If it doesn't pan out, have a look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/cutcopypaste.html).

```
$(this).live("paste", function(e) {
    alert(e.clipboardData); // [object Clipboard]
});
```

Comment: When I run this in Safari I get 'undefined' :(

Comment: clipboardData is sandboxed on most browsers (obvious security hole.)

Comment: Internet Explorer only!

Answer (score 9):

Listen for the paste event and set a keyup event listener. On keyup, capture the value and remove the keyup event listener.

```
$('.inputTextArea').bind('paste', function (e){
    $(e.target).keyup(getInput);
});
function getInput(e){
    var inputText = $(e.target).val();
    $(e.target).unbind('keyup');
}
```

Comment: This is very good, but it doesn't work for right click pasting.

Comment: neither does it work for middle-click pasting (X11)  it only works if they used the keyboard to paste.

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#textboxid").on('input propertychange', function () {
    //perform operation
        });
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

This is getting closer to what you might want.

```
function sanitize(s) {
  return s.replace(/\bfoo\b/g, "~"); 
};

$(function() {
 $(":text, textarea").bind("input paste", function(e) {
   try {
     clipboardData.setData("text",
       sanitize(clipboardData.getData("text"))
     );
   } catch (e) {
     $(this).val( sanitize( $(this).val() ) );
   }
 });
});
```

Please note that when clipboardData object is not found (on browsers other then IE) you are currently getting the element's full value + the clipboard'ed value.

You can probably do some extra steps to dif the two values, before an input & after the input, if you really are only after what data was truly pasted into the element.

Answer (score 6):

```
 $('').bind('input propertychange', function() {....});
```

This will work for mouse paste event.

Comment: This is best usage of all.

Answer (score 5):

How about comparing the original value of the field and the changed value of the field and deducting the difference as the pasted value? This catches the pasted text correctly even if there is existing text in the field.

http://jsfiddle.net/6b7sK/

```
function text_diff(first, second) {
    var start = 0;
    while (start < first.length && first[start] == second[start]) {
        ++start;
    }
    var end = 0;
    while (first.length - end > start && first[first.length - end - 1] == second[second.length - end - 1]) {
        ++end;
    }
    end = second.length - end;
    return second.substr(start, end - start);
}
$('textarea').bind('paste', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var orig = self.val();
    setTimeout(function () {
        var pasted = text_diff(orig, $(self).val());
        console.log(pasted);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This code is working for me either paste from right click or direct copy paste

```
   $('.textbox').on('paste input propertychange', function (e) {
        $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') );
    })
```

When i paste `Section 1: Labour Cost` it becomes `1` in text box.

To allow only float value i use this code

```
 //only decimal
    $('.textbox').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 46 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } 
       if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
            return true;
       } else if ( e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
            e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

See this example: http://www.p2e.dk/diverse/detectPaste.htm

It essentialy tracks every change with oninput event and then checks if it’s a paste by string comparison. Oh, and in IE there’s an onpaste event. So:

```
$ (something).bind ("input paste", function (e) {
    // check for paste as in example above and
    // do something
})
```

Comment: So it is impossible just to get the paste text when the event occurs?

Comment: Well, I guess you will have to deal with it yourself, like, compare the before and after. It has to be rather easy. But why don’t you just revalidate the whole input? Slow?

Comment: I just thought that would be possible to do but I guess not, Right now I'm trying another method by pasting it into a textarea and then transfering it to its final destination. I'm hoping that will work.

Comment: You just have to find the maximum matching fragment in the beginning of two strings (before and after). Everything from there and up to the lengths difference is the pasted text.

Comment: @IlyaBirman no it isn't: eg the pasted text may be replacing part (or all) of the original

Answer (score 4):

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
    if(e.clipboardData.types.indexOf('text/html') > -1){
        processDataFromClipboard(e.clipboardData.getData('text/html'));
        e.preventDefault();

        ...
    }
});
```

### Further:

- [Clipboard API and events](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#events)

Comment: text/html is not valid, only url and text.

Comment: @Mike I copied the snippet directly from the referenced documentation.

Comment: I tried this for about a day.  text/html never would work.  I ended up adding a timeout of 0 delay and was able to grab the html from the div where they were pasting in.  If someone had a working fiddle that would help.  Maybe im just doing it wrong...

Answer (score 1):

This method uses jqueries contents().unwrap().

1. First, detect the paste event
2. Add a unique class to the tags that are already in the element into which we are pasting.
3. After a given timeout scan through all the contents unwrapping tags that don't have the class that you set earlier. Note: This method does not remove self closing tags like 
   **See an example below.**

   ```
   //find all children .find('*') and add the class .within .addClass("within") to all tags
   $('#answer_text').find('*').each(function () {
   $(this).addClass("within");
   });
   setTimeout(function() {
   $('#answer_text').find('*').each(function () {
       //if the current child does not have the specified class unwrap its contents
       $(this).not(".within").contents().unwrap();
   });
   }, 0);
   ```

Comment: Definitely the best, shortest and self speaking answer ever seen!!!

Thank you so much, you made my day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Script to remove special characters from all fields with class portlet-form-input-field:

```
// Remove special chars from input field on paste
jQuery('.portlet-form-input-field').bind('paste', function(e) {
    var textInput = jQuery(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        textInput.val(replaceSingleEndOfLineCharactersInString(textInput.val()));
    }, 200);
});

function replaceSingleEndOfLineCharactersInString(value) {
    <%
        // deal with end-of-line characters (\n or \r\n) that will affect string length calculation,
        // also remove all non-printable control characters that can cause XML validation errors
    %>
    if (value != "") {
        value = value.replace(/(\x00|\x01|\x02|\x03|\x04|\x05|\x06|\x07|\x08|\x0B|\x0C|\x0E|\x0F|\x10|\x11|\x12|\x13|\x14|\x15|\x16|\x17|\x18|\x19|\x1A|\x1B|\x1C|\x1D|\x1E|\x1F|\x7F)/gm,'');
        return value = value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,'##').replace(/(\#\#)/gm,"\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a description of the relevant sanitization and why it may help solve the poster's issue? Simply providing a code block doesn't really help the OP (or future searchers) understand how to solve the problem - it just encourages copy/pasting misunderstood code.

Answer (score 0):

This proved to be quite illusive. The value of the input is not updated prior to the execution of the code inside the paste event function. I tried calling other events from within the paste event function but the input value is still not updated with the pasted text inside the function of any events. That is all events apart from keyup. If you call keyup from within the paste event function you can sanitize the pasted text from within the keyup event function. like so...

```
$(':input').live
(
    'input paste',
    function(e)
    {
        $(this).keyup();
    }
);

$(':input').live
(
    'keyup',
    function(e)
    {
        // sanitize pasted text here
    }
);
```

There is one caveat here. In Firefox, if you reset the input text on every keyup, if the text is longer than the viewable area allowed by the input width, then resetting the value on every keyup breaks the browser functionality that auto scrolls the text to the caret position at the end of the text. Instead the text scrolls back to the beginning leaving the caret out of view.

Comment: onpaste is called before the contents are pasted in.  You need a timed delay of at least 4ms to create your own afterpaste function, to wash the results of the paste.

Answer (score -2):

> There is one caveat here. In Firefox, if you reset the input text on every keyup, if the text is longer than the viewable area allowed by the input width, then resetting the value on every keyup breaks the browser functionality that auto scrolls the text to the caret position at the end of the text. Instead the text scrolls back to the beginning leaving the caret out of view.

```
function scroll(elementToBeScrolled) 
{
     //this will reset the scroll to the bottom of the viewable area. 
     elementToBeScrolled.topscroll = elementToBeScrolled.scrollheight;
}
```

Comment: This seems entirely off topic

Comment: It was a response to the answer given by James Tindall. Should have been a comment, but it's been over a decade, so I think the statute of limitations has passed.