# Reading from dragged and dropped excel table

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I'm working on struts 2 with hibernate 3.
I've a functionality of Importing from excel doc in it.
I found how to import from excel file once the file is uploaded by using the following code.

```
try {
    File uploadToBatch=new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Book2.xls");
    Workbook w;

    w = Workbook.getWorkbook(uploadToBatch);

    Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);

    System.out.println(sheet.getName()+"  "+sheet.getColumns()+"  "+sheet.getRows());

    for(int i=0;i<sheet.getRows();i++)
        for(int j=0;j<sheet.getColumns();j++)
            System.out.println(sheet.getCell(j, i).getContents());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    //addActionError(e.getMessage());

    // return ERROR;

}
```

Now what I want is when the user drags some rows from excel file and drops into the webpage I have to get the values and pass it to server.
I can't use an ActiveX object since it must support all operating systems and browsers as well.

Please give me some ideas.

Comment: probably this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006468/copy-paste-from-excel-to-a-web-page

Comment: Thanks Basav.. That was useful. But I'm still searching for some more stuffs like that...

Comment: The only way is to split fields on tab and rows on newlines there isn't going to be anything more.