# Inserting data into database from HTML table generated at client side

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database

I have generated a HTML table using copying data from Excel file and pasting it in a textbox and running jQuery to parse it.

To achieve this I followed the question-
[Copy/Paste from Excel to a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006468/copy-paste-from-excel-to-a-web-page)

Now the next requirement is I need to insert data from this HTML table into database table.

How can this be done in ASP.NET web forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an ASP page that accepts the data, parses the '`,``and``tags into rows of values and then do a SQL`INSERT` statement.

But why first encode it into the '`,``and`` fields in the first place? Why not paste the data and submit it to your server, and then, on the server do the parsing?

```
var rows = data.split("\n");

for(var y in rows) {
    var cells = rows[y].split("\t");

    // call sql 'INSERT' supplying cell[0]  ... cell[n]
    // as the arguments values of  the INSERT         
}
```

}