# HTML forms for mass numerical data input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm looking for a HTML form for mass data entry. Something where the user can copy and paste a column of data from Excel directly into the form. The data will then be used in JavaScript as an array and eventually used as an x axis on a scatter plot.

So far I've just used standard numerical data entry forms. However, this forces the user to enter the data one value at a time. The user will be dealing with potentially tens of thousands of data points, so this is obviously far too time consuming.

```
<form id = "xColumnInput">
  <input type = "number" name = "" id = "xColumn">
  <br>
  <input type = "number" name = "" id = "xColumn">
  <br>
  <input type = "number" name = "" id = "xColumn">
  <br>
  <input type = "number" name = "" id = "xColumn">
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0):

Something similar has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006468/copy-paste-from-excel-to-a-web-page).
In your case, you could give a textarea to paste the excel data and run js to make the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using save web page as on your .xls file may solve the problem to you unless you need additional condition such as modifying the value. Did you try this? https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/03/21/convert-excel-html/

Answer (score 0):

I can not think of a way to do this in plain HTML.

One way to do this would be to have a single large text field for each column, and then use Javascript to parse the pasted text into an array, and then onto a scatter plot.

The data can even be displayed as a table.