# Copy and paste specific data from an Excel sheet to a web page based on a specific condition, repeating this process more than 1000 times

Tags: excel, automation, copy-paste, matching, import-from-excel

I am looking for a solution to copy specific cells from an Excel spreadsheet containing over 1000 names. Each name is associated with a number in an adjacent cell. I need to copy these numbers and paste them into specific text boxes on a web form. However, the numbers can only be pasted if the name in the Excel spreadsheet exactly matches the name associated with the text box on the web form. i'm not programmer

automate copy and past for excel to webpage

Comment: So perhaps edit this to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2006468/4961700

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an automation thing, you are switching applications, and you're not a programmer, I suggest you consider using either macros or a script language. These can help you automate some of the mundane steps in your process: switching applications, find/select/copy data, and even repeating the process a bit.

If you haven't or considered using [the Excel Macro Recorder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/quick-start-create-a-macro-741130ca-080d-49f5-9471-1e5fb3d581a8#:%7E:text=then%20click%20Save.-,Record%20a%20macro,click%20OK%20to%20start%20recording.), do that. I don't think an Excel macro will suit for your complete process, but at least it will get you going.

The next step is probably to consider [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). AHK is not exactly a *beginner* tool ... but you can probably pick up an existing script that will help automate at least part of your process.

It will not be possible for anyone to give a clearer or more specific answer without an example of your spreadsheet and webpage. Consider posting those so others can comment.

This is a common task and challenge - if you have already done some research or tried things, mention those, too.

And keep researching and trying things!