# Setup Extjs GridPanel to allow pasting from clipboard

Tags: javascript, extjs, clipboard, extjs4

I would like to setup Extjs GridPanel to allow pasting from clipboard. Ideally, I would like to be able to paste a matrix copied from Excel directly onto the GridPanel - does anyone know of an existing method of doing this? or any thoughts on where to start implementing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with listening to the [`onpaste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onpaste) event on the GridPanel. You'll probably have to do some work with getting it to bubble up correctly to your handler.

Hopefully you'll then have a mess of text from Excel to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

There are two extensions for copy/paste actions on Grid Panels :

[Excel Editor Grid](http://www.developerextensions.com/index.php/extjs-excel-copypaste-grid?tmpl=demo)

and another [useful one](http://www.crp.de/Shared/extjs/examples/copyPasteExample/copyPasteExample.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a similar method to [this other question on HTML tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095131/paste-excel-data-into-html-table) if you're using IE only. Otherwise, I don't think you can get access to the clipboard in all browsers.

You may want to consider exporting from Excel as a CSV file and importing it into your application.