# jQuery Spreadsheet/Grid plugin with copy/paste from/to Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, grid

I am looking for a jQuery plugin for something like spreadsheet or grid. 
I have found a lot of jQuery Grid [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations) and one spreadsheet [plugin](http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet).
But I would like functionality with copy/paste cells from/to Excel. Something like [here](http://www.developerextensions.com/index.php/extjs-excel-copypaste-grid)  Any suggestions?

Comment: https://jsgrids.io/ is a list of JavaScript grid libraries. You can filter the results for libraries, such as those that have copy and paste support, or those that export to Excel.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I needed JavaScript data grid with copy/paste compatibility with Excel. I could not find such, so I created this: http://handsontable.com/

Maybe you will find it useful.

Comment: Does it support forumlas?

Comment: Yes: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/demo-formula-support.html (there is a demo link)

Comment: This simple description ("I created this jQuery plugin") belies the completeness of this solution: a full-blown web-based spreadsheet with formulas, API, documentation and support.  Wow.

Comment: Thanks :) Btw it does not require jQuery anymore. I will edit my answer

Comment: An alternative for handsontable is jExcel. Some examples can be found at:
http://www.bossanova.uk/jexcel/tracking-changes-on-the-spreadsheet

Answer (score 2):

there is one available on github: https://github.com/TanyaWebDesign/SpreadSheet

it is based on jquery, has copy/paste and bunch of other functions.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with tabular data with jquery is probably using [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples)

I did a plugin for copy/paste from/to excel:
http://labs.nereo.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-excel-compatible-spreadsheet.html

The plugin has now many bugs fixed and features added by the community (eg. undo/redo support) :
https://github.com/Celebio/SlickGrid/commits/master

Comment: Check this out
http://www.bossanova.uk/jexcel/tracking-changes-on-the-spreadsheet