# Cakephp : Creating a spreadsheet that captures and saves data in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, phpexcel, vendors

Hie guys, i have a system running in cakephp and I have a requirement to create a platform to capture marks and calculate them as a percentage of 30 in other words I am supposed to model the functions of excel (including formulas for adding and multiplying) into the cakephp app. I have gone through PHPExcel but im failing. Any idea of what i can use? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so related with CakePHP. I would say, with Javascript.

Here you have a great plugin to deal with tables:
http://handsontable.com/

I found it some days ago here, created by @warpech:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997458/1081396

Comment: I want a grid that can be viewed and edited. I have a table that stores the student's id and for columns for marks. The grid should list all the student ids and allow the teacher to enter marks per student just like in excel with the cells every assignment contributes a certain percentage of 30.

Comment: I have oriented you. What I can not do is giving you the concrete solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mark = 25;
$percentage = $mark / 30 * 100;
```

or using Excel, if mark is in cell B1
then C1 formula is

```
=B1/30*100
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am stuck in even displaying an editable grid in cakephp that saves to the database.