# What grid is behind spreadsheet in google doc?

Tags: javascript, google-closure

Tired of various half-usable grids, I would really love to lay my hands on the grid/table component behind spreadsheet in Google Docs.

What I'm really keen on is the ability to navigate with keyboard, intuitive in-place editing and support for complex editors (like date picker, which indeed seems like the one from Closure).

Is it by any chance available as open source?

Comment: The closest thing I have seen is http://handsontable.com/index.html, which appears to be currently maintained and [well-received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019158/jquery-spreadsheet-grid-plugin-with-copy-paste-from-to-excel). I don't think the actual Google grid is open source (too bad) though I've favorited this question in case anyone knows differently.

Comment: @TimMedora Yes, I am using Handsontable now, I have some issues and I'm looking for alternatives. Handsontable gets quite painful as soon as you leave the "happy path" the creator imagined and has numerous bugs.

Comment: the docs grid is not open source since it relies on a heavy server side component as well. reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/closure-library-discuss/x1afFp9Y1Ho%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: @lennel Make it an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!