# How to create Excel like spreadsheet with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have been shifted on a new project where i need to create spreadsheet for my web page. It is exactly like the Google spreadsheet. For now i don't have any idea how i could do this. I have googled for the same but no luck.

Could anyone guide me how i could achieve this.

Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: search for "mvc export to excel". I just found tons of results on google for this.

Comment: brad i want excel like interface over web not the export feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd rather look to JS/JQuery spreadsheet and grid plugin rather than being stuck to MVC3.

Have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019158/jquery-spreadsheet-grid-plugin-with-copy-paste-from-to-excel) where many plugins have been mentionned. You should find one that fits to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, its really what i was searching for.