# Convert Clipboard excel data as Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, clipboarddata

I'm trying to access copied Excel data via clipboard in JavaScript. I find the options to `getData` in the format of plain text or `text/html`.

**If it has to be created as one object, is looping and parsing over the data as text/html or plain text the only option?**

Ex- the expected output object of the copied excel data shall be,

```
[{column1 : value1,column2:value 2},{}];
```

This is the code I'm using for accessing clipboard data

```
document.body.addEventListener("paste", function(e){
    var clipboardData, oData;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    oData = clipboardData.getData('text/html');
});
```

Comment: Did you search before asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095131/paste-excel-data-into-html-table

Comment: @epascarello: Did you read the highlighted part of the question ? I was actually looking out for some hack solutions if already available instead of looping over plain text / html. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: There is no solutions other than really looping.