# how to handle copy/paste in iframe design mode?

Tags: javascript

How can i handle copy/paste events on iframe in design mode? i need to change text (reformat it, add proper tags, etc) before copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you pop up a dialog containing an area for the user to paste into, you need to do this in a slightly hacky way involving redirecting the paste to an off-screen div. I've written about this on Stack Overflow before: [Get html from clipboard in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787669/get-html-from-clipboard-in-javascript/2787936#2787936)