# MS Word like DOM manipulation in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, ms-word

Have a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WorbTh0IMTY&feature=youtu.be). In MS Word, one can drag any element anywhere. Based on that, the remaining content (only text, in this video example) reflows and wraps to fit. For example, when two images are side by side and one is dragged away or towards the other, the text in between shrinks or expands accordingly.

Is it anyhow possible to mimic such behavior in HTML, with Javascript? The biggest difficulty I find is the fact that elements *own* their content in HTML. So, a `span` owns its text, a `div` owns its text. But in the video, we can see that the text element in between the images hasn't exactly any content of its own, it gets whatever fits into it while transferring text from left to right. That is why, its content changes with change in orientation. Also, its text is not continuous. It contains bits and pieces of multiple sentences.

Are such manipulations possible with HTML and Javascript? If so, any heads-up will be nice...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at css exculsions:

http://adobe.github.com/web-platform/samples/css-exclusions/

it might help you acheive what you want. note that it is an experimental feature.

Comment: Well, that is indeed an experimental feature, and it is not supported in almost any browser..