# Get html from clipboard in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce, clipboard

I want to copy/paste images in Rich Text Editor (tinymce). In Chrome, I use the following code to get the image and it works well,

```
event.clipboardData.getData('text/html')
```

But in IE11, the functionality will be broken using following code,

```
window.clipboardData.getData('text/html')
```

I can only get image name from clipboard using following code,

```
window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
```

How should I get copied image from clipboard in IE11?

Comment: Someone explained it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787669/get-html-from-clipboard-in-javascript/27279218#27279218