# how to retrieve RTF content from ClipBoard using javascript/JQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to retrieve the RTF content from the Clipboard(Orginating from MSWord).
Is it possible to retrieve it using javascript / JQuery methods?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. You can only get it if the user triggers a paste. WebKit provides [a means to access the clipboard during a `paste` event](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/CopyAndPaste.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001234-176911) and IE provides a [`clipboardData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object that sometimes allows this (depending on the security settings) but that's it.

You can use a hack to effectively redirect a user paste into an off-screen element. See my answer here: [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/2177059#2177059)