# Is it possible to get pasted text without using the setTimeout() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timeout, paste

I found out that when pasting text (i.e. `Hello`) by using the mouse, the following function will throw an empty popup:

```
$('input:text').onpaste = function()
{
    alert($('input:text').val());
});
```

The thing is, when the onpaste event is being fired, the text is not yet actually pasted to the input field (at least that's my guess). So changing the function to:

```
$('input:text').onpaste = function()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        alert($('input:text').val()
    }, 100);
}
```

gives a correct result by showing a popup with the text `Hello` when pasted to the input field.

Now my question: is there is any possibility to catch the pasted text without using the `setTimeout()` function? This workaround seems quite dirty so I'd love to not have to use it.

kkthxbai
xon1c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19269040/530153

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use the `oninput` event instead, modern browsers support this method

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/KDLjf/

```
$('input').bind('input', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: How can I check if the input was a paste?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:text').bind('paste', function() { 
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This code does not work, because the pasted value was not set in the input yet. I have tested using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the data being pasted:

```
$("input:text").bind('paste', function(e) {
     var text = e.event;
     alert(text);
});
```

The timeout is needed to get the dom updated so the value is actually in the input field. you could also use the change event to check if the input box is updated http://api.jquery.com/change

Comment: I'm getting "undefined" in the alert, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the bellow code works on IE8 since the input value is not changed when alert() executed.

```
 $('input').bind('input paste', function(e) {
     alert($(this).val());
 });
```

on Firefox and Chrome, it works fine.