# checking number or not when some text is pasted in a textbox (without set time out)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have an input field like this

```
<input type ="number"   id="numberTxt" placeholder="Number Only"/>
```

I am checking whether the value is a number or not and clearing back as the following function using `keypress` event

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(numberTxt){
          $('#numberTxt').keypress(function(event) {  

              var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
              if (charCode != 45 && (charCode != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
              {
                   return false; 
              }
              else 
                   return true;

          }); 
       });
    </script>
```

> BUT when we **copy paste some text (CTRL V CNTRL C)** the above code is
>   **not working**

or that i tried this function below 
but not getting the value of the input at that point 
its "" (empty string).
when we copy paste its correctly triggering this function.

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#numberTxt').on("paste",function('numberTxt') {  

                 var val = $('#numberTxt').val() ;  

              }); 
           });
</script>
```

**Is the any another way to get the input tag's value with event ,
if i pass the event like the keypress function before**

any other Suggestions or answers to check number during copy paste will also be helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747439/detecting-value-change-of-inputtype-text-in-jquery

Comment: Note that you'll probably want to allow for drag'n'drop too. Or you could just remove any unwanted characters in a `blur` handler... If using jQuery you can safely use `event.which` - no need for the test and the `event.keyCode` fallback because jQuery normalises `event.which`.

Comment: Can i get textbox value with event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might well feel below function correct using `.bind('input'.....`

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/KDLjf/  got this one from

[Is it possible to get pasted text without using the setTimeout() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398275/is-it-possible-to-get-pasted-text-without-using-the-settimeout-function)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you validate only integer value on **PASTE**

```
$('#numberTxt').on("paste",function(e) {  
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        var val = $this.val(), 
            regex = /^[\d]+$/;
        if( regex.test(val) ){
            $this.val( val );
        }
        else{
            $this.val('');
        }
      alert(val);    
    },0);

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/LaN8f/1/

Comment: I need a way without settimeout.

Comment: @Reshma what's the problem with `settimeout()`

Comment: i need to do a filter with that textbox and do a set of filling of more that 10 textbox and html according to the value in the text box. and need to do these filtering with a little bit more amount of data  in 3 to 4 arrays. timing is really a issue for me . so i need to know any faster way . thats all.