# How to clean up HTML on-paste in my WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg, paste

I have created a WYSIWYG HTML editor and I noticed that when you paste text from Word, it comes in with its source formatting and I don't want it. Is it possible to clean that up when it gets to the editor.

What I need the most is being able to clean-up the text before it get to the editor itself. Something like an "onPaste" thing that can allow me to filter my text when it's pasted (using the command or keyboard shortcut).

Comment: Could you give a sample of the resulting text when you paste from Word into your editor? I might still be unable to help, but as I don't use Windows I'm unable even to try and work that out, currently.

Comment: Please don't sign posts.

Comment: There is a `paste` event listener you can use. It is called on any type of 'paste' action and allows you to cancel the paste. I'm actually working on a WYSIWYG right now, but am just flagging the content for cleanup and altering the DOM after the paste (in contenteditable div), rather than fixing it before the paste.

Comment: linked - [get clipboard data on paste event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2176861/104380)

Answer (score 4):

HTML Purifier will create standards compliant markup
http://htmlpurifier.org/
Or http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/

If those don't help you, I suggest you switch to FCKEditor or tinymce which has this feature built-in.

Answer (score 0):

you could easily set the InsertMode like this

```
{
  InsertMode: "insert_only_text"
}
```

from the [docs](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/docs/modules/types.html#InsertMode-1)