# Processing paste to contentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, paste

I'm creating my own custom WYSIWYG editor, and I'd like all HTML to be removed from pasted content.

I do this by focusing a textarea on the paste event, then after a 10 millisecond timeout, I insert the contents of the textarea into the contentEditable.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JPM6p/

This is working great in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox or Internet Explorer. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Apparently it works in Firefox 6.0.2 on Mac OS X, so perhaps it works only in earlier verions of Firefox?

Comment: Works on Mac OS 10.7 Lion in FF 6.0.2, Safari 5.1.1, and Chrome 17.0.963.46.

Comment: @DC_ That's weird, maybe it only works in earlier versions of FF?

Comment: Just a heads-up: I've used contentEditable a fair amount (we use it in a few places on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)) and I've found it to be a source of many bugs. Browsers don't agree on how certain things should be handled, such as line breaks in pasted content. In other words, good luck! :s

Comment: @davidchambers Do you know of any other methods to create a rich-text editor in the browser?

Comment: I prefer using a markdown editor or pagedown, such as the one SO here uses. It has a little bit of a learning curve, but it is much more consistent.

Comment: use rangy.googlecode.com for contentEditable. Works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to focus the textarea before the paste event fires in some browsers, which means you can only realistically use this technique for pastes triggered by keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>. Here's a similar question with more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177059/96100

Comment: Ctrl + v is not working sometimes in firefox v-29 browser. If I resize the browser window then I am able to paste. (paste event is triggering). Is there any problem with firefox 29 browser with contenteditable or paste event with keyboard short cuts (ctrl + v) ?

Comment: @Jak I'm seeing a problem in FF29 on Windows with pasting marked-up text into a contenteditable. Straight text works fine.