# Accessing paste event data with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-events

In a Vue app I have a paste `listener` on a `textarea` with the intention to run validation code when the user pastes data into this field. When I log the paste event I can see in the console that the data that was pasted into the field is there under `event -> target -> value`. I can't seem to access this with `event.target.value` though. What am I doing wrong?

Minimal example:

```
<div id="app">
  <textarea name="myField" @paste="onPaste"></textarea>
  <p>Field name: {{ fieldName }}</p>
  <p>Pasted data: {{ pasted }}</p>
</div>
```

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fieldName: '',
    pasted: ''
  },
  methods: {
    onPaste(event){
        console.log(event)
        this.message = event.target.name
        this.paste = event.target.value
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/feg8pcmv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your jsfiddle has a minor typo (`this.paste` instead of `this.pasted`).

Secondly, you need to use the "getData" method from the clipboardData property to access the text.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event

```
this.pasted = event.clipboardData.getData('text')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zfuwy9ep/

That said, if you want to get the whole string inside the text area after something was pasted, you could wait until the current items in the event queue have been resolved, and read the value of the textarea afterwards

```
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('textarea contents', event.target.value);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjq1bw5u/

Answer (score 2):

Currently (as of now) according to MDN docs regarding [`onpaste event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste)

> The paste event fires when the user attempts to paste text.
>
> Note that there is currently no DOM-only way to obtain the text being
>   pasted; you'll have to use an nsIClipboard to get that information.

And since [Clipboard API/events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) are in draft, supporting older browsers may not be achieved.

One not so neat solution is to use `setTimeout`:

```
  methods: {
    onPaste(event){
      setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(event);
      this.fieldName = event.target.name;
      this.pasted = event.target.value }, 100);
    }
  }
```

[More info can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857801/how-to-get-the-new-value-of-a-textarea-input-field-on-paste)