# Is there a non-Flash way to set/get the clipboard data in WebKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit, clipboard

I want to set or get **data** or text to the clipboard, but without flash. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the clipboard data in WebKit, but only during a paste event, for security reasons (random websites being able to copy from your system clipboard at any time would be bad). Assuming you have a a text input with id "textBox":

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qc4s8/

Code:

```
document.getElementById("textBox").onpaste = function(evt) {
    alert(evt.clipboardData.getData("text/plain"));
};​
```

References:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/appleapplications/conceptual/safarijsprogtopics/tasks/copyandpaste.html
- http://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/
- [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)