# Javascript OnPaste

Tags: javascript, input, copy-paste

I have this right now:

`<input type="text" placeholder="Paste text" onPaste="alert(this.value);">`

This does infact work, except, it returns a blank alert window. I don't get any value. Help?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `onpaste` event fires before the `input`'s `value` is changed. You need something such as a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Paste text" onPaste="var e=this; setTimeout(function(){alert(e.value);}, 4);">​
```

I'm storing a reference to `this` inside a global var as `this` is not accessible inside the scope of a timeout function which is attached to the window object.

I'm using 4 miliseconds as the Timeout as it's the minimum valid Interval/Timeout in the HTML5 specification. **Edit:** As noted in the comments, you may also use `0` miliseconds as timeOut which is automatically recalculated to `4`. [**jsPerf tests**](http://jsperf.com/smallest-timeout/8).

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/HzkCw/)

You may as well use a function call inside your `onpaste` event passing `this` as a parameter to prevent your HTML mixing with JS too much. :)

And here's a function easier to read and which you can use in multiple inputs:

```
function pasted(element) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert(element.value);
    }, 0); //or 4
}​
```

Which can be called with simply `onPaste="pasted(this)"` for any input.

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/HzkCw/1/)

Comment: @DmitryScriptin Yes it can, but in the HTML5 specification it will be interpreted as 4 even if you set it to 0 (there are some test cases in jsperf to prove that), so I used a valid number to prevent re-calculations. :)

Comment: I prefer "0" for a "queued event", as then I don't have to guess what the *intent* is (that and it makes for consistent code) although just *omitting* the value should also suffice. There will **no** performance impact for a "re-calculation".

Comment: @pst Both will be interpreted at the same time, I guess it's more of a programmer preference. I'll add it on my next edit. :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It is. As long as the reason for such choices are stated ... at least there is reasoning occurring, differences aside ;-)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I updated the post with `var` to avoid clobbering `window.e`. (Global properties are never closed-over, but can appear to give that effect until a re-entrant situation is encountered...)

Comment: Thank you @pst, I'm not very fan of inline JS inside HTML, hence I updated with a new function as well. =]

Comment: Not working in 2023 (Safari).

Answer (score 12):

This is because the `onpaste` event fires **before** the content gets pasted into the element ([link](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuimtmq.php)) so it's not there yet at the time you handle it.

Modern browsers support methods of obtaining clipboard data inside the event handler. Refer to [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser) for cross-browser solution attempts.

Also, you can always work around your issue by simply starting a timer in the event handler function (10ms should be enough) that would check your input value later.