# Capturing mouseclick on an asp.net Textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, textbox

I've got a popup box which allows a user to type a brief (50 character) note.  What I need to do is figure out how to prevent the user from copy/pasting a note using the right mouse click.

I looked up all the [events available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox(v=vs.110).aspx) for a textbox, and onkeyup and onkeydown are not in this list but they do have an effect.

I have the following JavaScript that captures keystrokes:

```
<!--//**********************************
    // Comment Character Count
    //**********************************  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
     if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
     else
        countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
     }
 </script>
```

And then this textbox which calls the above function when a key is pressed:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textbox" Wrap="True" 
Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" Rows="3" runat="server"  
onkeyup="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" 
onkeydown="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" />
```

Everything works awesome, except when someone right-clicks and chooses "Paste", it bypasses the check because no keys are pressed.  Any ideas on how to trap for that?  Is there an undocumented onmouseclick event I can call or something?

Comment: IIRC, I think there might be an `onpaste` event. Also, an `onchange` event that might be useful. I'm only working from memory, so I might be mistaken...

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add an `onpaste` event to your TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textbox" Wrap="True" 
Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" Rows="3" runat="server"  
onkeyup="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" 
onkeydown="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);"
onpaste="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" />
```

Next, adapt [Fabrício Matté's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10972973/5233918) solution to handle the timing difference between `onpaste` firing and `value` being populated:

```
function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        else
            countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;

    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for all potential uses and abuses.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `TextBox.MaxLength` property. It'll prevent from adding additional characters even when pasting a text. You can also add asp.net custom validator to be sure the user hasn't changed you html in the browser editor.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textbox" Wrap="True" 
Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" Rows="3" runat="server" MaxLength="50"/>
```