# Standardized HTML way to chain input tags

Tags: html

I have an HTML form with three consecutive `input` tags with a `maxlength` attribute. Users are expected to give a 3-part code in these fields (let's say, a serial number).

Is there any **HTML** way to tell the browser that these fields are linked to each other?

---

For instance, browser could then move cursor from the 1st `input` to the 2nd when its `maxlength` is reached; or handle copy/paste properly; or provide a better autocomplete like completing the 3 fields at the same time (instead of one after the other, independently).

I know there are Javascript code floods that could provide these features (ie [Javascript OnPaste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972954/javascript-onpaste#10972973) ), but it would be up to me (aka website) to manage them, and won't allow use to set up its preferences as browser-side would.

Comment: What you have explained is only possible with javascript. It would be way to advanced to add attributes to input elements on how they should behave on input.

Comment: @Persijn We can set a `name=table[...]` so browsers could behave differently knowing those inputs are "chained". If there's no HTML way, is there a standard micro-format that describes such "chained inputs"?