# How to have JS onpaste event work with Rails form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, onpaste

I have a search form, and would like it so that when I paste something into the form, it automatically submits the form. I would also like to retain functionality so if I don't paste something, and rather manually type it, that I have to press enter/search button for it to work.

Here is my form:

```
<h1 class = "CustomerTitle">Search Tool</h1>
<%= form_with url: "/support/search_res", class: "form", method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :query, class: "input", placeholder: "Search for a user..." %>
  <%= form.submit "Search", class: "submit_button", id: "pasteSubmit", onpaste: 'pasteAndGo()' %>
<% end %>

<script>
  function pasteAndGo() { 
    document.getElementById('pasteSubmit').submit(); 
  }
</script>
```

Could somebody tell me why this is not working?

Edit: I've tried Sercan Tırnavalı's approach:

```
<h1 class = "CustomerTitle">Revuto Customer Support Tool</h1>
<%= form_with url: "/support/search_res", class: "form", onpaste: 'pasteAndGo()', method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :query, class: "input", placeholder: "Search for a user..." %>
  <%= form.submit "Search", class: "submit_button" %>
<% end %>

<script>
  function pasteAndGo() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0].submit(); 
  }
</script>
```

with no progress. Any other ideas/solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have the `onpaste` in the wrong place.
Please try this:

```
<h1 class = "CustomerTitle">Revuto Customer Support Tool</h1>
<%= form_with url: "/support/search_res", class: "form", method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :query, class: "input", placeholder: "Search for a user...", onpaste: 'pasteAndGo()' %>
  <%= form.submit "Search", class: "submit_button" %>
<% end %>

<script>
  function pasteAndGo() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0].submit(); 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This definitely did help. it works now. However, it doesn't take the information of the text field. It is always an "empty" paste. This may just now come down to the JS function itself.

Comment: @MislavRukonic please refer to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10972973/587518 it seems the onpaste event gets fired before the field value gets the pasted value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked out this post, and it seems that this was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should select form and submit it, not the button.

```
<script>
  function pasteAndGo() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0].submit(); 
  }
</script>
```

Also you can use this js library for this type functionality https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. At least this time, I don't get any errors in the console. Thank you for your response nonetheless.

Comment: Should `submit` be used or `requestSubmit`?

Comment: requestSubmit doesn't do the trick either.