# Select menu inside a jQuery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I'm having a Firefox issue. On Chrome for example, when I select an item, the menu behaves like it should But on Firefox, when I try to make a selection the dropdown disappears.

Any ideas? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/YEH9c/4/

Comment: [You may read this about the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I find way better to use mousenter and mouseleave for this situations, check this...

http://jsfiddle.net/snS3u/