# Disallow spaces typed or pasted into a text input and keep text and caret position the same

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I have a text input that I don't want spaces in.  If someone types a space or pastes text with a space, I would like to change the text back to what it was before the space was inputted AND also keep the caret position the same.  Maybe there is an easier way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

This is what I have so far:

```
<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>

<input type=text id="inputText" value="testValue" onInput=doIt(this);>

</body></html>​
```

And the javascript that would be included (I used jsFiddle):

```
var editedValue = "testValue";

// alert(editedValue);

function doIt(that)
{

var caretPos = that.selectionStart;

if (that.value.indexOf(" ") != -1)
{
that.value = editedValue;
// alert(caretPos);
that.selectionStart = caretPos;
}
else
{
editedValue = that.value;
}

}​
```

It seems to all work, except for, if the caret is in the middle of the text, and you type or paste spaces, the caret does not return to the original position.

Can anyone help me figure this out?  Or show me an entirely new/easier/simpler way to not allow spaces typed or pasted into a text input?

Here is the jsfiddle I was trying it with if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/djSnL/4/

Comment: have fun: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser

Comment: Yikes!  That does not look fun, lol.  Basically I can already detect the paste, and if it contains a space, keep the text the same as it was before...but why doesn't the caret get moved where I want it afterward?  I want it to stay in the same place.  Maybe something to do with the order things are done using the input event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/djSnL/5/

You want to capture the `onkeydown` event:

```
function doIt(e)
{
    var e = e || event;

    if (e.keyCode == 32) return false; // 32 is the keycode for the spacebar

}

window.onload = function(){
    var inp = document.getElementById("inputText");

    inp.onkeydown = doIt;
};
```

Note that they will still be able to paste spaces into the input, so you'll have to handle that as well.

To handle pasting, it's as simple as: http://jsfiddle.net/djSnL/7/

```
function pasteIt(e)
{
    var e = e || event;

    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g,'');

}
```

With both, you'll get the desired effect.

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe only webkit browsers will let you know what the data is before it's pasted: http://jsfiddle.net/djSnL/8/

```
function pasteIt(e)
{
    var e = e || event;
    var data = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

    if (data.match(/\s/g)) return false;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is a nice and simple solution, but I do want to use the input event handler so I can respond on pasted text as well.  The question is mostly how to do it for pastes using the input event, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but that just removes the spaces from a paste, whereas I wanted it to not paste anything if it included spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I got it, using jQuery.  Thanks for all the help!

// Bind Events

```
function bindEvents()
{
$(inputText).bind('keydown paste', checkForSpaces);
}
```

// Check For Spaces

```
function checkForSpaces()
{
if (event.type == "keydown" && event.which == 32) {return false;}
if (event.type == "paste" && event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain').indexOf(" ") != -1) {return false;}
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, because I don't have to store the text or caret position of the text inputs for after the paste, because the paste is simply canceled and doesn't occur if it contains spaces.