# javascript/ jquery autotab through form from paste data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to make it easy to fill in a form by allowing users to write a text file beforehand and copy/paste into the form. Whenever a tab or newline is detected, the form would tab over to the next input field.

Autocomplete won't help, as the form data will change with every use. Capturing keyDown events doesn't work either, as the keys pressed are ctrl+v, not the keys I want to capture. Is there a way to accomplish this? I have access to any JS plugins I can get my hands on to complete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capturing paste events can be done using the `onpaste` event and `clipboardData`

[This answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6804718/94278) you how to accomplish this. Then you would have to parse the incoming data accordingly.