# It is possible to expand a textarea only with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea with 200px of height, but when I pass that 200px with text I want to have the textarea expanded instead of keeping the 200px of height with a scroll bar.

It is possible to do that only with CSS?

Comment: No it is not possible to do only with css

Comment: Here is a great example of what is possible to do with textarea using CSS: http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/ I believe what you are looking for is 7. Auto-resize to fit content.

Comment: From Mason240's comment, http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/ , **section #7. Auto-resize to fit content** uses jQuery/JavaScript *not* CSS, despite the title.  As user1317647 states above, it is not possible with CSS only but requires script.

Comment: see this answer for how to do it with js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize (doesn't requite much js, oninput event and `rows = split("\n").length` works well)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Instead of `textarea` , you can use `div` with [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```

[*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/ARuce/)

Comment: +1 Very nice approach. In cases we can replace `textarea` with a `div` it works and is well supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable.

Comment: How can I remove the border when I select that div? When I select that DIV in Chrome it shows an awful blue border.

Comment: @swayziak  Maybe [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/outline) is what you're looking for.

Comment: The only problem is that this kind of element isn't passed by defauld when the form is submited, it is necessary to use Javascript to handle this

Comment: Agree with Marcio 100%

Comment: Cursor didn't appear with this solution in iOS, so unfortunately doesn't quite cut it

Comment: Another problem is that if you copy and paste formatted text into the box, [you get HTML inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125217/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-contenteditable) there.

Comment: With large texts editing becomes not responsive as in textarea.

Comment: You're kinda genius in HTML thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Engineer is there a more modern answer to this question now or is your answer still the better option?

Comment: Pressing `Enter` inside the editable area creates a new editable area. That seems like an important bug in the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work on iphone. It highlights like an input and open keyboard but typing does nothing and you can't select the text/move position of text insertion. --also, since you need Javascript to handle it anyway, better to use textarea and handle size change with javascript: `if(textarea.scrollTop!=0) textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px"` and `textarea{ overflow: hidden;resize:none;}` in css

Comment: A downside of this approach is that you can't use the placeholder attribute

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to make a textarea expandable by the user, using just CSS. In fact, in some modern browsers, such expandability is even the browser default. You can explicitly ask for it:

```
textarea { resize: both; }
```

Browser support is growing but is still limited.

There is typically just a small hint about resizability: a resize handle in the lower right corner. And I’m afraid most users won’t understand this hint.

You cannot make a textarea expand *automatically* by content using just CSS.

Comment: That should be "**lower** right corner", I think...?

Comment: Right, Doin. I fixed this. (And when writing direction is from right to left, the handle appears in the lower left corner.)

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible to do only with css, but you could use jquery:

```
$('#your_textarea').on('keydown', function(e){
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.scrollTop()) {
        $(this).height(function(i,h){
            return h + 20;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, but it is very easy with JS:

```
let el = document.getElementById(`myTextarea`);
el.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (el.scrollTop != 0)
    el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + "px";
});
```

In my case I have a list of player names and I am doing this in a loop for each player.

```
              humansContainer.innerHTML = humans
                .map(
                  (h, i) =>
                    `<div><textarea id="human_${i}" type="text" value="${h}">${h}</textarea></div>`
                )
                .join("");
              humans.forEach((h, i) => {
                let el = document.getElementById(`human_${i}`);
                el.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
                  let name = el.value;
                  if (el.scrollTop != 0)
                    el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + "px";
                  humans[i] = name;
                });
              });
```

Answer (score -13):

Here's a simple, pure php and html, solution, without need for js, to make the textarea fit to size.
   HTML: 
`<textarea rows="<?php echo linecount($sometext, 100, 3);?>" cols="100" name="sometext"><?php echo $sometext;?></textarea>`

```php
    <?php
   /* (c)MyWeb.cool, 2014
   * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *Calculate number of rows in a textarea.
   *  Parms :   $text:      The contents of a textarea,
   *            $cols:      Number of columns in the textarea,
   *            $minrows:   Minimum number of rows in the textarea,
   *  Return:   $row:       The number of in textarea.
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
   function linecount($text, $cols, $minrows=1) {
   // Return minimum, if empty`
   if ($text <= '') {
    return $minrows;
   }
   // Calculate the amount of characters
   $rows = floor(strlen($text) / $cols)+1; 
   // Calculate the number of line-breaks
   $breaks = substr_count( $text, PHP_EOL );
   $rows = $rows + $breaks;
   if ($minrows >= $rows)   {
    $rows = $minrows;
   }
   // Return the number of rows
   return $rows;
   }
   ?>
```

`And this one is even shorter and better:

```php
function linecount($text, $cols, $minrows=1) {
    if ($text <= '') {return $minrows;}
    $text = wordwrap($text, $cols, PHP_EOL);
    $rows = substr_count( $text, PHP_EOL )+1;
    if ($minrows >= $rows) {$rows = $minrows;}
    return $rows;
}
?>
```

Comment: This won't expand the text area on the client side as the user types more text. It's also not a great idea generally - you can't measure text by counting characters unless you're using a monospace font.