# Auto expanding textarea but not with JS

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

I'm expecting the answer to be no, however is it at all possible to make textareas expand automatically to show all text entered with css3 and html 5? I dont want to use jQuery, we have that already implemented but it is slowing the web app down so much as it's looking per keypress

Comment: possible duplicate of [It is possible to expand a textarea only with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865982/it-is-possible-to-expand-a-textarea-only-with-css)