# Paste client clipboard in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I'm searching for a way to paste the image from client clipboard as a div background or canvas. All the ways lead me to ZeroClipboard, but in instructions I didn't find anything about getting content from clipboard, not copying to it. How can I paste the image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ZeroClipboard is flashed based, it's bound to the limitations that Adobe has set forth:

*Note: Content running in Flash Player or in a non-application sandbox in AIR can call the getData() method only in an event handler for a paste event. In other words, only code running in the AIR application sandbox can call the getData() method outside of a paste event handler.*

Therefore, no, you cannot get the contents of the clipboard outside of a `paste` event.

[Link to the full article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS2F6A31B9-1AE6-4b23-9C12-57A33F4F0516.html)