# Getting clipboard data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using Html5 and JQuery.

### Html

```
<canvas style="border:1px solid grey;" id="cc" width="1000" height="800">
```

### Javascript:

```
var pasteCatcher;
if (!window.Clipboard){
 if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")>0){
    pasteCatcher = document.createElement("div");
    pasteCatcher.setAttribute("id", "paste_ff");
    pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
    pasteCatcher.style.cssText = 'opacity:0;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;';
    pasteCatcher.style.marginLeft = "-20px";
    document.body.appendChild(pasteCatcher);
    pasteCatcher.focus();

    document.getElementById('paste_ff').addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
        if(pasteCatcher.children.length == 1){
                        var canvas = document.getElementById("cc");
                         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            img = pasteCatcher.firstElementChild.src;
            var img2 = new Image();
            img2.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
                }
            img2.src = img;
            pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
            }
        },false);
    }
 }
```

Above code is working fine. When the clipboard has image then that will be set to canvas.
**IF the clipboard has text then how can i get the text and draw in canvas**?

Thanks!

Comment: It is also working in FF.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read it that well, I thought you where doing something that would require Flash.

Comment: No..no flash is required..It is working fine when clipboard has an image.Now if the clipboard has text then how can i get that text and fill the text in canvas?

Comment: Without the user pasting that text into the canvas, just extracting it from the clipboard ?

Comment: nope..user clicks ctrl+V then only we need to extract it and set into canvas since FF has security issues..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, access to the clipboard varies across browsers for security reasons.

Even the methods used to read/write the clipboard vary.

**A workaround:**

**Have the users paste the text into an html textarea and then read the textarea value.**

The benefits of the workaround are:

- The user must paste somewhere anyway, so let that be the textarea.
- The textarea can be edited by the user if they desire.
- The textarea value is not restricted for security reasons, so it works cross-browser.