# How to get the clipboard client content and send it to server as a file

Tags: java, clipboard

I am developing a Java/J2EE application, and I want to upload a file to my server with the client clipboard content.

I developed a Java applet but I have an access denied failure to get the client clipboard. Does anybody have any ideas that can help me? Any OCX plugins that could resolve the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is [very limited **JavaScript** code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser) (= non crossbrowser) and either with **AJAX** or with an **applet** (JS can pass the string to the applet) you may receive the text.

Comment: Thank you for your response, 
my problem is not how to pass information from applet to server. but how can i retrieve the image clibboard. applet dose'nt work, and i want using a java code.

Answer (score 0):

thank you Joop, follow to your poste i found this link that describe, how we can get image clipboard with javascript code: [Pasting image from clipboard](http://codebits.glennjones.net/copypaste/pasteimagedata.htm)