# How to replicate Word online's ability to detect bolded characters in pasted text in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, clipboard, copy-paste

If I copy text from Word that contains bolded characters and paste it into a contenteditable DIV in IE the bolded characters are preserved.  However, if instead I get the text from the clipboard via Javascript using the `window.clipboardData.getData()` method then I receive the text in plain-text with `\r\n` characters where the line breaks should be, but I don't see any indication of what text might be bold.

Is it possible that the 'bold' marker is using some sort of non-printing character in the text that I could detect and replace with a `<b>` tag? If so what is that character?

I notice that if I go use Word online then it is able to preserve the bold text in pasted content from IE so it seems possible, but I have no idea how they're doing it.

Comment: Hi, no.... copyclipboarddata is plain text (utf-8).

Word and Office documents use RichText which includes the markup for decorated text... When you paste back into a word document you will see two options for pasting .. rich text and plane text.
see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983016/how-to-paste-rich-text-from-clipboard-to-html-textarea-element