# can i get string value from type number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have input with type number like this

```
<input type="number" class="number" min="0" max="999999" value="0" id="id">
```

when i use this code

```
$("#id").val();
```

if it's number like `1` it return the number

but if not a number  like `1+1` it return empty string `""`

so can i get the actual value with type number or i have to change to text to do so

i test it with chrome and firefox

i know that it will work with type text

but i'm looking to faster solution if there are non then i will change it to text and rewrite the code

---

here is my question
now when i change the type to text using jquery it remove the value can i change it without remove the value ?

```
$('#id').attr('type','text')
```

what i want to do is make the type text get the value and return it back to number

Comment: what ouptut you want for `1+1`, 2 or just `1+1`

Comment: `.val()` returns the string value of the input element. if you want to convert it to an actual namber use `parsefloat` or `parseInt`

Comment: yup i want to be 2 at final but when it's `1+1` id return just `""`

Comment: @robert, `1+1` in not valid for `type=number` it `Specifies that its input element is a precise control for setting the element’s value to a string representing a number.`

Comment: i edit the question please read the last part

Comment: you cannot change type to type to text without changing attribute. You will have to change your css. Either way it's better to style everything with classes than attributes as it will go really bloody on bigger projects

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki i want to change the attribute indeed but when i do the value inside the number is gone and the value of the text is just like it's in js `""`

Comment: You can get value to variable, change attribut and set number again. Probably the easiest solution

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki can't do it the variable will have empty string `""`

Comment: if you test it and work write the code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do it with `<input type='number'/>`,

`<input type="number" >` will expect you to put a number, so if you put anything like `1+1`, it is not considered a number, so returns an empty string "".

you can instead use `<input type=text/>`

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/ob5t6tyx/1/)

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var strVal = $("#id").val();
  var intVal = eval(strVal);
  alert(intVal);

})
```

```html
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="number" value="0" id="id">
```

**Edit:**

if you cant change whole html, you can change type of the element using jquery,

```
$('input[type=number]').attr('type','text')
```

just put this on page load

Comment: i know that using text will solve it but i build the site with number now i must rewrite the whole code again

Comment: @robert.. yes you must rewrite the code again, since input type number will simply discard any NAN value from it

Comment: the thing is not i can't change it because it will take time to change `number` to `text` it will take time cause my code depend on the type `number` and the width of the inputs will take more because when i limit the value to 99999 it take smaller width but when it back it will take wider width i know i can fix it again to be just like it now with type text but it need time

Comment: in that case you will need to spend time on it.. there is no way you can support + sign inside input number

Comment: @robert see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/ob5t6tyx/2/ .. value is retained there, you need to change type to text before user starts inputing values in it.. nut when he enters anything.. usually you do it on page load

Comment: I have the same need. The point is that on mobile type="number" will show the digits pad, this is a WANTED feature, instead when type text, the mobile shows the keyboard letters. So the question could turn in: how to validate user input on submit in a type="number"? And one more: how to validate user input on a paste action in a type="number"? This second question is a need too, because the user can paste a number copied from somewhere else but it may end containing dashes, blank spaces and others chars

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs an `input type="number"` , there is a reason.

Premise: I'm not the same Robert that made the initial question :-)

but ...

I was exactly in the same situation of the Robert who made the initial question ( destiny matter? ), anyway

making a deeper research, I have found this answer
[JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/6804718#6804718)

I beloved that twice because, nevertheless, it is pure vanilla javascript

I have made this code with `input type = "number"` and it works like a charm

*The main behavior because **I want** `input type = "number"` is that this input type, when focused ON MOBILE will open the numbers pad INSTEAD than the letters keyboard. Here the input is driven, you can press only numbers and dashes*

*But in my app , they can paste the number.. so having a check on the paste event, is a logical consequence*

try it

```js
function handlePaste (e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;

    // Stop data actually being pasted into div
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    
    // Do whatever with pasteddata
    alert(pastedData);
}

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

```html
<p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a "paste" event to an input type="number" element. Paste some text in the input...</p>

<input type="number" id="myInput" value="Try to paste something in here" size="40">
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Solution to your problem

```
$('input[type=number]').each(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).attr('type','text');
  $(this).val(val);
});
```

above code will work on all inputs with type number. If you want to use only one use class or id in first line. If you want to count value from string like 1+1 u can use eval in try catch block. But this is generally a lot more complicated solution.

Comment: val will have empty string `""` try it yourself