# Vaildate information inside TEXTAREA via jQuery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following textarea value:

```
<textarea name="field" id="field" rows="5" class="form-control"
placeholder="Describe your guests" required="">
Checkin(dd.mm.yyyy): 29.07.2015
Checkout(dd.mm.yyyy): 30.07.2015
Last Name: Johnson
First Name: James
Date of birth(dd.mm.yyyy): 12.12.1995
Country Code: ISR
Passport Number: 150150150
Visa: Type D 1520 or Visa:
</textarea>
```

I want to vaildate the Checkin information, Checkin(dd.mm.yyyy): has to be dd.mm.yyy otherwise throw an error, Country Code: has to be 3 digits all uppercase for example? I know it is much easier to vaildate each field individually. I need to vaildate pieces inside the textarea.. preferably via jQuery. Any suggestions?

Comment: What will you handle if user misedited the Labels, like `Checkin(dd.mm.yyyy): 29.07.2015` becomes `Cci(mm.yyyy): 29.07.2015`?

Comment: I wanted to somehow hold this form and make it unchangeable via jQuery too. so if someone copy information it will "auto fix" it...

Comment: I'd suggest you use some divs and add `contenteditable`  attr to them, then use `css` to decorate them as a large `textarea`. If you don't want the inputs.

Comment: @fuyushimoya so the user will have to fill-up each div?

Comment: Does the `textarea`'s values no need? You still can set text as initial value to them.

Comment: @fuyushimoya this might be something that can help me, is there any example live? Thanks

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d32o1qtg/3/) is something like this you're looking for?

Comment: @fuyushimoya this is sort of it. Is it possible to copy-paste, the whole content, and the values will be autofilled? I remember I saw it somewhere can't find it.. Same way Codeacademy vaildate thier "textareas" code fields..

Comment: I've answer a question about copy&paste [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30942717/1737627), you can see how to get text from clipboard and insert to each `input`, should share some idea, however, I'm not good at validating, can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using bootstrap or similar templates CSS, you could easily use their validation tools (much cleaner and easier). However, with simple HTML I like to use http://jqueryvalidation.org/ This website provides great tutorials and videos as well.

Comment: I am aware of regular form vaildations.. I am looking to vaildate custom made textarea..

Answer (score -1):

How about using javascript regular expressions?