# clipboardData not working when copying text to content editable element in Chrome on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, clipboarddata

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7o8qzckp/1/)

I have read that copying plain text from `clipboardData` to a content editable element isn't supported in Chrome on Android ([like this post](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/issues/623)). When you run the example above on mobile, which aims to remove all formatting from pasted text, the `text` variable returns an empty string. This only happens in Chrome on Android. So I'd like to know if there is a workaround for that.

Example code modified from [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

```
$('#editableDiv').on('paste',function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      var text;
      if( e.originalEvent.clipboardData ){
        text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

        if(text === ''){

           console.log('Android Problem');  

        }

        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
      }
      else if( window.clipboardData ){
        text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
      if (window.getSelection)
        window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode( document.createTextNode(text) );
      }
      console.log(text);
});
```

Updated: I have come up with a workaround by triggering a popup for users to paste text. Not ideal but could get the job done removing formatting. I'm looking for more workarounds/suggestions.

```
   if( e.originalEvent.clipboardData ){
    text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    if(text === ''){       
        text = prompt('Paste something..');  
    }
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).bind("paste", function (e) {
      text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
      alert(text);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.