# Do "Paste" command when clicking to a context.js menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Well, i've created a page with its own contextual menus, and now i'm implementing a text editor into it, but i cannot code the "Paste" button, Do you have a clue of how to force the "paste" event to happen?

[image]

```
context.attach('#app', [
            {text: 'Refresh', action: function(e){ location.reload(); }},
            {divider: true},
            {text: 'Copy', action: function(e){ document.execCommand('copy', false, null); }},
            {text: 'Cut', action: function(e){ document.execCommand('cut'); }},
            {text: 'Paste', action: function(e){ Event(paste); }},
        ]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, read the article.