# JQuery Texteditor: keep format when I copy & paste text from somewhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, jqte

jQuery Text Editor: Remove pasted formatting that is not allowed

I am using the jQuery Text Editor, a wysiwyg editor to create rich formatted HTML in a textarea input.

I can initiate the editor in my javascript code and allow / disallow certain formatting options. But when I copy & paste text from somewhere else (Word, E-Mail client, etc.), it keeps all the formatting, even if I disallowed this particular formatting option in the editor.

Is there any smart way to strip all HTML formatting that I disallowed? Or even better can I tell the editor to strip disallowed formatting automatically that is pasted?

Comment: I believe the answer can be found in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/2177059#2177059

Comment: not the same @JamesAllen

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).on("paste", ".jqte_editor", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

    //Do required strip of HTML elements

    document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("paste", ".jqte_editor", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

    //Do required strip of HTML elements
    document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
});
```

The above code I have tried but when I copied it from excel to jQuery richtext the formatting was lost.