# Using clipboardData in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to access data from the clipboard in TS1.6 using the following:

```
$(container).bind("paste", (e) => {
    var data = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
});
```

But it just gives me the following build error:

> Property 'clipboardData' does not exist on type 'JQueryEventObject'

If I remove the 2nd line and debug it in Chrome 46, I can get at the clipboard data just by calling

```
e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
```

I can't see clipboardData in the JQueryEventObject interface in the latest version of jQuery.d.ts but the question is - should it be there or is there a different way of retrieving data from the clipboard that TS currently supports?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Comment: Since Typescript 1.5 Property clipboardData has been removed from type Window. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes.

Comment: It also looks like ClipboardEvent is being introduced in 1.8 so may just have to wait for that. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5363

Comment: Check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49922802/486867

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems until TS1.8, one (hacky) option I have found is to just extend `Event` with this:

```
interface Event {
    clipboardData: any;
}
```

I'm sure I could improve this by replacing `any` with something better, but it works for now.

Comment: For other folks also stuck on pre-1.8 in some project: it's `clipboardData?: DataTransfer`.

Answer (score 14):

Use ClipboardEvent type (e.g.)

```
private onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    const {clipboardData} = event;
    const pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can bypass the expected typescript type using the ["property"] approach

```
 var pastedData = e.originalEvent["clipboardData"].getData('text');
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast `Event` to `ClipboardEvent` like this:

```
element.bind('paste', (event: Event) => {
    let clipboardEvent: ClipboardEvent = <ClipboardEvent> event;
});
```

Comment: I think it is need convert the original event: <ClipboardEvent> event.originalEvent
I you find it right - please edit your answer.