# Detect Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V in an input from browsers

Tags: angular, directive, keyboard-events, onkeydown

I am using the direct following and I do not detect the copy and paste with the keys inside the input, would someone know how? Thank you!

```
export class OnlyNumberDirective {
    // Allow decimal numbers. The \, is only allowed once to occur
    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/[0-9]+(\,[0-9]{0,1}){0,1}$/g);

    // Allow key codes for special events. Reflect :
    // Backspace, tab, end, home
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'Delete', 'Del', 'Ctrl', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Left', 'Right' ];

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('keydown', [ '$event' ])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): string {
        // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return null;
        }

        // Do not use event.keycode this is deprecated.
        // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode
        let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        // We need this because the current value on the DOM element
        // is not yet updated with the value from this event
        let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
        if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return null;
        } else {
            return next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You simply can do who : *for information this code manage all mac user who user CMD instead of ctrl*

```
@HostListener('window:keydown',['$event'])
onKeyPress($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) && $event.keyCode == 67)
        console.log('CTRL + C');
    if(($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) && $event.keyCode == 86)
        console.log('CTRL +  V');
}
```

If you want to detect other kind of shortcut :

- event.ctrlKey
- event.altKey
- event.metaKey (Aka Cmd for mac user)

[Online sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4phzqw)

--- UPDATE AFTER COMMENT ---

You may can do something like this

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.bindKeypressEvent().subscribe(($event: KeyboardEvent) => this.onKeyPress($event));
    }

    onKeyPress($event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if(($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) && $event.keyCode == 67)
            console.log('CTRL + C');
        if(($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) && $event.keyCode == 86)
            console.log('CTRL +  V');
    }

    private bindKeypressEvent(): Observable<KeyboardEvent> {
        const eventsType$ = [
            fromEvent(window, 'keypress'),
            fromEvent(window, 'keydown')
        ];
        // we merge all kind of event as one observable.
        return merge(...eventsType$)
            .pipe(
                // We prevent multiple next by wait 10ms before to next value.
                debounce(() => timer(10)),
                // We map answer to KeyboardEvent, typescript strong typing...
                map(state => (state as KeyboardEvent))
            );
    }
```

or if is not working, just :

```
private bindKeypress(): Observable<KeyboardEvent> {
    const typeOfEvent = this.deviceService.getKeybordEvent();
    fromEvent(window, typeOfEvent)
    .pipe(
        // We map answer to KeyboardEvent, typescript strong typing...
        map(state => (state as KeyboardEvent))
    );
}
```

Where `this.deviceService.getKeybordEvent();` is method who return type of event base on User Agent. [massive list of user agent can be find here](https://gist.github.com/enginnr/ed572cf5c324ad04ff2e)

Comment: Check out my answer for angular way of handling this problem :)

Comment: with you answer i have learn new thing, thanks for sharing us. On @Mario case, and because he have to manage many other short code, i think my approch will be easier to use.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! The problem is that I need it to work for me in Internet Explorer, too, and it does not work there.

Comment: Means your method inside `OnlyNumberDirective` is never call ? if yes, just try to play around `keypress` and `keyup`, by memory i already have experiment this issue.

Comment: Yes, it is called but for each browser it is different.

Comment: @MarioRamosGarcía i have update my answer, i hope this will help you to manage your issue.

Comment: deviceService? what is this btw?

Comment: @Vincent-cm according to the line `fromEvent(window, typeOfEvent)` i guess is service helper who return string like `keypress` `keydown`, to help to configure who UI react to user interaction.

Answer (score 17):

Angular provides high level API for listening to key press combinations. Check out the following example.

**ctrl-keys.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ctrlKeys]',
})
export class CtrlKeysDirective  {
  @Output() ctrlV = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() ctrlC = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('keydown.control.v') onCtrlV() {
    this.ctrlV.emit();
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.control.c') onCtrlC() {
    this.ctrlC.emit();
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <input ctrlKeys (ctrlV)="onCtrlV()" (ctrlC)="onCtrlC()" >
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  onCtrlV() {
    console.log('ctrlV pressed')
  }

  onCtrlC() {
    console.log('ctrlC pressed')
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wez5yv)

Answer (score 6):

Just add this to any component. When the user performs the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>s</kbd> it will print 'Save Performed'

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.control.s', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log('Save Performed');
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>v</kbd> replace the 's' in 'document:keydown.control.s' with 'v'.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly import HostListener and create a method to listen to keyup event.
Also, use ctrlKey because keycode is deprecated.

```
import { HostListener} from '@angular/core';

    @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
       keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
          if (event.ctrlKey) {
              if (event.key === 'c') {
                 console.log('ctrl c');         
              }      
             else if (event.key === 'v') {
                 console.log('ctrl v')
              }
      }
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it can be pasted into the original directive and work

Answer (score 2):

Instead of monitoring the key events for copy and paste commands, I suggest handling the clipboard events (`copy`, `cut`, `paste`). In addition to taking care of the various shortcuts used on different platforms, it also detects the clipboard operations initiated with the context menu. Please note that the `paste` event can be cancelled with `e.preventDefault()`. You can see the code at work in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewmnh1).

```
@HostListener('copy', ['$event'])
onCopy(e: ClipboardEvent) {
  ...
}

@HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
  let clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.control.c', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

@HostListener('document:keydown.control.v', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30125864)