# Issue on restrict copy paste junk characters and symbols in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area which doesn't have max length. In that text area i am restricting the symbols and junk characters on keypress by checking with charcode>160 and able to restrict the junk symbols and characters. But when i trying to stop copy pasting the junk values, it does n't happen. Below I have copied the code which i tried for keypress and copy paste.

```
$("input[type=text], textarea").bind("keypress paste", function(event) {
        if (event.charCode>160 || !event.charCode) {
            alert("Not allowed characters/symbols");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
})
```

and some junk characters -- !íßÓÜØúƤ etc.

Comment: You may be better to create a regex which includes the allowed characters and removing those that aren't listed.

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser

Comment: there's no event.charCode when I paste 10 characters

Comment: Additional to Rory's comment, use `oninput` instead of `keypress` and `paste`. It takes care of a dropped text too.

Comment: Rory and Teemu, do you have any working example?

Comment: [A fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9129kwx2/). You can construct the regexp to contain any characters you need.