# How to catch event when some text added into textarea by copy paste or programmatically?

Tags: jquery

I want to catch event when some text added into a textarea by copy paste or programmatically so i can add some work about it.

How do i do that? Which jquery method should i use for that? Change method didn' t work.

```
$('textarea').on('change', function(){
--do some stuff;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste) event that you can intercept.

Below is an example

```
var yourElement = document.getElementById("yourElementId");

yourElement.addEventListener('paste', function(event) {
    console.log("The data that was just pasted was "+event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
});
```

Try it on the search bar at the right of the nav bar on StackOverflow in your browser, and see for yourself.

You can get a reference to it using

```
document.getElementsByName("q")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input` event to handle pasting done by users,

```
$('textarea').on('input', function(){
--do some stuff;
});
```

But this event will not be fired if you do it by programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

> ...by copy paste...

The copy/paste bit is easy on a modern browser: Catch the `input` event.

> ...or programmatically...

There's no event raised when the value of a textarea is changed programmatically. <s>The only way is to use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) watching for `subtree`, `childList`, and `characterData` changes. `MutationObserver` is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) other than in IE, where it didn't arrive until IE11. However, for most purposes, you can use a polyfill that uses the obsolete "mutation events" to provide a barebones `MutationObserver` shim. Just search for "MutationObserver polyfill" or "MutationObserver shim" to find options.</s>

To my surprise, setting the `value` of a `textarea` does not fire a `MutationObserver` on Chrome (some other things do, but not that). This means that in order to detect programmatic changes, you'll have to **poll** (blech!), keeping the old value and periodically (say, every 20-100ms) checking to see if it's different.