# How to add onpaste event to future created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind onpaste event to all the elements inside container, using jquery

```
$('.container').on("paste","*",function(e){});
```

But on my browser this is not working, and i think now their is no `on paste` event exist in jquery,
So i think i must use javascript

```
$('.container')[0].addEventListener("paste",function(e){});
```

This works fine but only works for class container , how can i bind this handler to all the future created elements in container

Any idea?

Comment: jQuery uses native events, so your first example should work, although note that the `paste` event is not very well supported in IE if that's what you're testing in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/paste

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so what should i do , for cross browser

Comment: `$(document).on('input','.container',function(){})` try this way

Comment: @beginner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/6804718#6804718

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nope, I will not use that

Comment: @beginner on addition of new elements in `.container`, you have to call this  line again `$('.container')[0].addEventListener("paste",function(e){});`

Comment: Not much else that can be done if you need IE support. Also note that you have a typo in your code: there's a `.` instead of a `,`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thing i can use onpaste attribue in new created elements, is it fine

Answer (score 2):

did you try this:

```
    $(".container").bind("paste", function(e){});
```

Comment: By "future created element" you mean: dynamically created elements? i.e you are creating elements dynamically using JavaScript and want "onPaste" event to be bound to them?

Comment: in this u are using , on paste attribute , it may be not fit in all cases , but i think it can solve my problem