# How do I fire from a <button> CTRL+V and CTRL+Z to a targeted <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, copy-paste, ctrl

I want to fire from a button <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to a targeted textarea. If it is possibility to have this as an `onclick` button instead of `id` button that would be perfect. How do I do that?

**NOTE:** Please do not misunderstand this post with detecting or alert keypress. I do **NOT** want that. I want to have a button that executes this keypress onto the textarea.

**My JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var t = document.getElementById('mytextarea'),
    bcsv = document.getElementById('bcv'),
    bsz = document.getElementById('bcz'),
    cv = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents'),
    cz = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents');

cv.initKeyboardEvent(
           'keydown', 
           true,     // key down events bubble 
           true,     // and they can be cancelled 
           document.defaultView,  // Use the default view 
           true,        // ctrl 
           false,       // alt
           false,        //shift
           false,       //meta key 
           86,          // keycode
           0
          );  
cz.initKeyboardEvent(
           'keydown', 
           true,     // key down events bubble 
           true,     // and they can be cancelled 
           document.defaultView,  // Use the default view 
           true,        // ctrl 
           false,       // alt
           false,        //shift
           false,       //meta key 
           90,          // keycode
           0
          );  

bcz.addEventListener('click', function(){
  t.dispatchEvent(cz); 
}, false);

bcsz.addEventListener('click', function(){
  t.dispatchEvent(csz); 
}, false);
</script>
```

**My HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="CTRL+V" id="bcv" />
<input type="button" value="CTRL+Z" id="bcz" />
<textarea id="mytextarea" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
```

**Question:** I never managed to make this work. So how do I make it work? Or is it another way to make this work?
How do I make two buttons to act as if I would push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on the keyboard on a targeted textarea? But without using the keyboard.

Comment: Ok, and what's the question? Does this work? if not, why not? You have errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: those variable names.....`bcsz`,`bsz`,`cz`,`cv`,`t`

Comment: I changed the `bcsz` to `bcsv` because there was a mistake. But now still not working.  @NateBeers

Comment: The question is clear. How do I make two buttons to act as if I would push CTRL+V and CTRL+Z on the keyboard on a targeted textarea? But without using the keyboard. I will not edit the post putting this question in to clarify what I want. I did find one error, but is now fixed and in the post too, but that was not the problem, because it still does NOT work and if I knew why I would NOT ask with a post of this here would I? @DarrenSweeney

Comment: CTRL-V does paste the clipboard data into the currently focused input element. To access the clipboard data, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser

Comment: I already have a copy code that accesses the clipboard and the copy code works. Now I needed a paste code with a button. The link you gave me, I have seen that page before and there is no place it tells me how to make that work with a button and besides that gives me the source codes of how to make an alert from the clipboard, I do not want an alert from the clipboard. I want to have a paste button. @mch