# In JavaScript, how to get the value while User pasting?

Tags: javascript

I tried to use the event API,
such as paste.

In my JavaScript code, it does not work.

when the user copy text from  form,how can I get the selected value?

**UPDATE**

I use following code and it works.

```js
function handlePaste(e) {
  var clipboardData, pastedData;
  // Stop data actually being pasted into div 
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get pasted data via clipboard API 
  clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
  // Do whatever with pasteddata 
  alert(pastedData);
}
document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: [This could help you achieve what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Comment: If you want to prevent the paste from happening, using an oninput might not work very well.

Comment: thanks for helping.
 I use following code and it works.
function handlePaste (e) {
  var clipboardData, pastedData;

  // Stop data actually being pasted into div
  e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

  // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    
    // Do whatever with pasteddata
    alert(pastedData);
}

document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);