# Get Value of Text Input after (paste) Event

Tags: angular

I´m trying to get the content of a text input field after something was pasted inside it. How can I fetch the data? My approach with `$event.target.value` I used for the keyup event doesn't work. If you paste something with `Ctrl + V` It works due to the keyup event, but if I try to paste something from the context menu of the browser it doesn´t work.

Here is a very simple Code sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input type="text" [ngModel]="value" (paste)="pasteEvent($event)" (keyup)="keyupEvent($event)">
  <br>{{result}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public result: string;

  public pasteEvent($event: any) {
    this.result = $event.target.value;
    console.log('paste: '+ $event.target.value);
    console.log($event);
  }

  public keyupEvent($event: any) {
    this.result = $event.target.value;
    console.log('keyup: '+ $event.target.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: What about `(ngModelChange)="pasteEvent($event)"` (emits on all changes, not only paste)

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, Your approach fits perfect for my needs. If you feel free to create an answer I will accept it.

Comment: thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to get the model updated when the user pasts something the same way as editing the value, you can just use

```
(ngModelChange)="pasteEvent($event)"
```

or two-way binding

```
[(ngModel)]="value"
```

If you actually want to handle the past event directly, the event should have a `clipboardData` property:

```
console.log($event.clipboardData);
```

To get pasted text, you can use `getData`:

```
console.log($event.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
```

See also

- [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/6804718#6804718)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste

Comment: Somehow the getData('Text') didn't work for me. I used (paste)="myMethod($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))"

Comment: @Gunter, when you say or two way binding, what is the proper way to check cilpboard value using the shortcut: [(ngModel)]="value"?

Comment: @JanatbekSharsheyev `[(...)]` is the closest to 2-way binding in Angular and only related for input/output combinations and not related to the clipboard or such.

Answer (score 3):

for  me below code worked :

```
(paste)="onPasteHandler($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))"
```