# How can I filter pasted values in intbox?

Tags: java, zk

I have an intbox that is accepting any text value when it is pasted. I don't want to disable control+c values in this intbox so how can I make it regect char values pasted?

Some code:

```
<intbox mold="rounded" id="intbxNumeroDaConta" width="90px" />
```

Some pictures:

[image: intbox]

[image: intbox with pasted value]

Comment: you can add a check onChangeValue

Comment: Or if there is something like onLostScope, it will be probably better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you paste a non-digital text, you shall see the validation error box when you blur the focus. This will hint users to fix their value.

The solution below works for chrome, firefox, IE 11 or above

```
<zk xmlns:h="client/attribute">
avoid pasting non-number characters
    <intbox h:onPaste="preventPastingNonDigital(event)" />
<script><![CDATA[
function preventPastingNonDigital(e){
    var pastedText = e.clipboardData ? e.clipboardData.getData('text') //chrome, firefox
     : window.clipboardData.getData('text'); //ie11

    if (!new RegExp('^[0-9]+$').test(pastedText)){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
]]></script>
</zk>
```

ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData

For older IE, they don't support `onPaste`, so please refer to [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)