# Get clipboard contents from firefox browser extension using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, clipboard

I'm writing a browser extension for Firefox and would like to use javascript to extract the contents of the user's clipboard WITHOUT using a "copy" or "paste" event listener. I reviewed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/6804718#6804718) but it won't work in my case because it uses a "paste" event listener to trigger the extraction of the user's clipboard contents. Is there a way to get the user's clipboard contents using Javascript without employing an event listener?

Comment: no, you need an approved user-initiated event fro security reasons.